# Javascript: Do I need a multi dimensional array, objects in an array or...?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have a dynamic variable that could be any integer from 5 to < 99 decided by the user.

```
var topLevelMenusTotalNum
```

Each top level menu has 5 fixed properties that I want to store which are mostly integers and some long numbers. And then recall for use in my bit of code.

Whats is the bext way for me to store these values in a storage system that can be dynamic in size?

I'm guessing I should store each top level menu as an object, with the 5 properties, i.e.

```
menu1.property1 = 500
menu1.property2 = 23
...
menu1.property5 = 24.3445345644
```

But how can I dynamically create the `menu1`, `menu2`, `menu3` etc objects depending on how many the user has created?

Should I create the objects in an array? Or something else?

Comment: What are the properties being used for?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen to store the number and widths of the menu items to split them into two columns if the menu is too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the order matter? If so, use an array.

Does the name matter? If so, use an object with named properties.

Do neither matter? Then it doesn't really make a difference. Arrays are slightly easier to loop over.

Comment: OK..I guess the name of the properties matter, not the order. The names will be the `.OuterWidth` of the odd and even numbered submenu items within a top level menu. I guess what I'm really asking is if it's actually possible to create objects dynamically without having to formally declare them first?

Comment: You said the names would be: `menu1, menu2, menu3`. Those are variable names. Don't use variables. If the order matters. Use an array. If the name matters use an object. You have to assign the object you want to store to the array or object property you want to store it in.

Comment: I'm sorry for not quite understanding - but when you talk about "does the order or the name matter", do you mean with respect to the top level menus themselves, or to the 5 properties of each top level menu?

Comment: The former, since that is what you were asking about.

Comment: OK. So the order of the top level menus is what matters as I need to know which is first, second etc. And the names of the 5 properties matters as I want to be able to differentiate between them. So I infer from what you've said that I need to store the menus as an Array, and then each of the menus needs to be an object which stores the 5 names properties. So a dynamically sized array, containing any number of menu objects each with 5 properties. Have I understood?

Answer (score 1):

if you have an object, you can dynamically add items to it like so:

```
var menus = {
    "menu1": {
        //properties
    },
    "menu2": {
        //properties
    } //etc...
}
```

then you could add to it like so:

```
menus['menu' + newMenuNR] = {'property1': 21, 'property2': 10} //<-- properties in there
```

this is fully dynamic and won't result in problems later on, to loop through the object, you could use a 2-dimentional loop.

```
for(menu in menus) {
    for(item in menu) {
        alert(item.['property1']); //displays property of item in menu in menus (replace property with your own property names)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so you are suggesting objects within objects? So the menus are properties of an object, and then the `property1`, `property2` etc of each menu are further properties of each menu property within the initial 'menus' object?

Comment: yes, this is basically how databases work, too:database > table > column  @Slab

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use an object for top layer and each object will contain array as class member.
Object will help you to create dynamically based on user and each object of user will contain an array which has five properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it with objects as long as the parameters can be named.

If you need a lot of objects, just keep an array of objects to search/sort/filter.

```js
//Class (Hide this in some library script)
var Menu = (function () {
    function Menu(parameters) {
        if (parameters === void 0) { parameters = {}; }
        this.node = document.createElement("ul");
        this.items = [];
        this.width = 100;
        this.height = 100;
        this.name = "";
        this.title = "";
        this.children = [];
        //Apply parameters
        for (var key in parameters) {
            if (parameters.hasOwnProperty(key) && this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this[key] = parameters[key];
            }
        }
        //Apply node parameter
        this.node.title = this.title;
        //Add to static
        Menu._menus.push(this);
    }
    Menu.prototype.render = function () {
        //Reset contents
        this.node.innerHTML = "";
        //Append sub-menues
        for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < this.children.length; childIndex++) {
            var child = this.children[childIndex];
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(child.render());
            this.node.appendChild(li);
        }
        //Append generic items
        for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < this.items.length; itemIndex++) {
            var item = this.items[itemIndex];
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = item;
            this.node.appendChild(li);
        }
        //Return node
        return this.node;
    };
    Menu._menus = [];
    return Menu;
}());
//Implementation
//create menu
var topMenu = new Menu({ items: ["Just testing"], title: "Super!" });
//Add anonymous submenues
topMenu.children
    .push(new Menu({ items: ["item 1"], title: "sub", name: "sub1" }), new Menu({ items: ["item 3", "item 2"], title: "sub", name: "sub2" }));
//Add to "bigList"
document.getElementById("bigList").appendChild(topMenu.render());
//Updates incoming
setTimeout(function () {
    //Find menu with the most items + children (Which is easy with named parameters)
    var m = Menu._menus
        .filter(function (a) {
        return a.title == "sub";
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return (b.items.length + b.children.length) - (a.items.length + a.children.length);
    })[0];
    //Add new item
    m.items.push("Sweet right?");
    //Update node
    m.render();
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () {
    //Find last menu
    var m = Menu._menus
        .reverse()[0];
    //Remove last item
    m.items.splice(m.items.length - 1, 1);
    //Update node
    m.render();
}, 4000);
```

```html
<div id="bigList">
Named parameters are lovely :-)
</div>
```